# How to implement Cassandra converter for java time LocalDate to datastax LocalDate?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, localdate, spring-data-cassandra

I have a spring data cassandra query which gets local date values in java.time.LocalDate format and I need to covert this value to com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate in cassandra configuration bean. How to implement this?
Example:

List listOfStudents = findStudentByStudentNumber();

Here, findStudentByStudentNumber() gets date in java.time.LocalDate format but List has com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate format. I need to define a @Bean in @Configuration class to convert this automatically. What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options.

Maybe the most straightforward is converting via year, month and day of month:

```
    java.time.LocalDate javaDate = // …;
    com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate staxDate
            = com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate.fromYearMonthDay(
                    javaDate.getYear(), javaDate.getMonthValue(), javaDate.getDayOfMonth());
```

This works since both java.time and Datastax number the months from 1.

A bit shorter and without risk of swapping arguments, so probably my preferrence:

```
    com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate staxDate
            = com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate.fromDaysSinceEpoch(
                    Math.toIntExact(javaDate.toEpochDay()));
```

Code has not been compiled. Please forgive any typos.

**Link:** [Documentation of `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/core/LocalDate.html)